# magento 2 "invalidAttributeName" Error while custom csv upload

Tags: import, csv

Here Am trying to upload a custom data with csv. Below are some code example

**import.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="messages" label="Custom Import" model="Company\CustomApi\Model\Import\CustomImport" 
    behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

**RowValidatorInterface.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\CustomApi\Model\Import\Entity;
 
interface RowValidatorInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Validator\ValidatorInterface
{
       const ERROR_INVALID_TITLE= 'InvalidValueTITLE';
       const ERROR_MESSAGE_IS_EMPTY = 'EmptyMessage';
    /**
     * Initialize validator
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function init($context);
}
```

**CustomImport**

```
<?php

namespace Company\CustomApi\Model\Import;

use Company\CustomApi\Model\Import\Entity\RowValidatorInterface as ValidatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;
class CustomImport extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity
{
    const ID = 'entity_id';
    const MESSAGE = 'message_deltail';
    const DATE = 'create_at';
    // const TABLE_Entity = 'messages';
    /**
     * Validation failure message template definitions
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_messageTemplates = [
    ValidatorInterface::ERROR_MESSAGE_IS_EMPTY => 'Message is empty',
    ];
     protected $_permanentAttributes = [self::ID];
    /**
     * If we should check column names
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;
    /**
     * Valid column names
     *
     * @array
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
    self::ID,
    self::MESSAGE,
    self::DATE,
    ];
    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;
    protected $_validators = [];
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    protected $_connection;
    protected $_resource;
    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data $importExportData,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data $importData,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
    ) {
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
    $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
    $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->_connection = $resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
    }
    public function getValidColumnNames()
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }
    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return 'messages';
    }
    /**
     * Row validation.
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum)
    {
    $title = false;
    if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }
    $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;
    return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }
    /**
     * Create Advanced message data from raw data.
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     * @return bool Result of operation.
     */
    protected function _importData()
    {
        $this->saveEntity();
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Save Message
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function saveEntity()
    {
    $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
    return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Save and replace data message
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function saveAndReplaceEntity()
    {
    $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
    $listTitle = [];
    while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
        $entityList = [];
        foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
            if (!$this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum)) {
                $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface::ERROR_TITLE_IS_EMPTY, $rowNum);
                continue;
            }
            if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                continue;
            }
            $rowTtile= $rowData[self::ID];
            $listTitle[] = $rowTtile;
            $entityList[$rowTtile][] = [
                self::ID => $rowData[self::ID],
                self::MESSAGE => $rowData[self::MESSAGE],
                self::DATE => $rowData[self::DATE],
            ];
        }
        if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE == $behavior) {
            if ($listTitle) {
                // if ($this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique(  $listTitle), self::TABLE_Entity)) {
                //     $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_Entity);
                // }
            }
        } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND == $behavior) {
            // $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_Entity);
        }
    }
    return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Save message to customtable.
     *
     * @param array $priceData
     * @param string $table
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData, $table)
    {
    if ($entityData) {
        $tableName = $this->_connection->getTableName($table);
        $entityIn = [];
        foreach ($entityData as $id => $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $entityIn[] = $row;
                }
        }
        if ($entityIn) {
            $this->_connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $entityIn,[
                self::ID,
                self::MESSAGE,
                self::DATE,
        ]);
        }
    }
    return $this;
    }
}
```

**CSV file is**

[image]

**Import page**
[image]

Where Am doing wrong. can I get help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed UnderLines and added only text, and same updated in CSV rows so it working fine

```
const ID = 'entity_id';
const MESSAGE = 'message_deltail';
const DATE = 'create_at';
```

To this

```
const ID = 'entity';
const MESSAGE = 'message';
const DATE = 'create';
```

Answer (score 1):

## Compare the Columns

no of columns import by csv  = no of columns you declare in $validColumnNames

if no of column not match some time. you will get this error